# meteor sends a false generated link (#) by using "forgot your password" function

Tags: meteor, reset-password

I activate the function "forgot your password?" in meteor. I got an email from meteor in my Inbox to reset the password, everything is woking fine, but the problem is in the generated link, because i got # in the Link. (see the link among)

```
http://localhost:3000/#/reset-password/8DhEtotkn0A0EU-
kShhmB6llHlfXpXCXAIqNYvrsZzi
```

When i remove the # from the link above and copypaste the link in my browser, then it's working fine.

where comes # in the link? and how can i remove it in my meteor project to get a correctly link to rest password?

help is needed, thanks

Comment: This is the default link that is generated by `accounts-base`. It is picked by `accounts-client` and calls any callbacks that you may have registered with `Accounts.onResetPasswordLink()`. How did you setup your reset handling process?

Comment: i used the     https://www.mailgun.com/    . and  i added only this 
  
  process.env.MAIL_URL="smtp://postmaster%40sandbox202f4c3b9d397531e92b47ef.mailgun.org:004c72789XXXXXXXXXXXXX608b512a@smtp.mailgun.org:587/";

Comment: how can get setup accounts.onResetPasswordLink()?
where can i find  Token?

Comment: You get it in the callback. It's a convenience method that the accounts package sets up for you. It is documented [here](https://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-onResetPasswordLink). You can, of course, build your own solution that analyzes the URL or your own custom route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this using the `Accounts.urls.resetPassword` function

In your `server/main.js` file insert the following code:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Accounts.urls.resetPassword = function(token) {
        return Meteor.absoluteUrl('reset-password/' + token);
    };
});
```

You can set whatever URL you want above.

Also you can add more info to customise the email if you want:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    Accounts.urls.resetPassword = function(token) {
        return Meteor.absoluteUrl('reset-password/' + token);
    };
    Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = "Your Application Name";
    Accounts.emailTemplates.from = "Application Name <no-reply@yourdomain.com>";
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i added the basic code above in    server/main.js    but i still get a generated code with hash http://localhost:3000/#/reset-password/0dBUFCho9gQI0P43Cmvg-zFdF1U2LI2YjA2IM9dCd9J

Comment: No prob, did it work for you? If so can you accept it as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: no it still doesn't work. when i click on the generated link in my inbox , i get in my browser   http://localhost:3000#  the rest will be droped

Comment: should i schange something in this code. Meteor.startup(function() {
    Accounts.urls.resetPassword = function(token) {
        return Meteor.absoluteUrl('reset-password/' + token);
    };
});

Comment: i didn't find main.js in Server file i found it in .meteor\local\build
so i added it in this file .meteor\local\build

// The debugger pauses here when you run `meteor debug`, because this is 
// the very first code to be executed by the server process. If you have 
// not already added any `debugger` statements to your code, feel free to 
// do so now, wait for the server to restart, then reload this page and 
// click the |▶ button to continue.; 
it is right @sean?

Comment: You should never add code to the .meteor file. Remove the code from there. Create a new folder in the root of your application (not inside the .meteor folder) called ```server``` and then a file called ```main.js``` inside there with the code I posted!

Comment: The problem of Hash is fixed with your suggested code above. Thank you, but the generted link send me not to the 'reset password'  page. it send me to the 'sign in page'.
Any advice please?

Comment: the problem of my last comment was related to the configuration
you can find the correct Configuration in this link: https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/issues/410 .
 i hope it will be helpfull for the next generation